# Power switch for 8Pin ATX Connectors

Tags: power-supply, relay, atx, analog-switch

What would be the best way to make a power switch for the 8-pin ATX Power Connectors? Can I just join all the yellow (12V) wires together and then use a high current switch to toggle them ON/OFF? Also instead of a switch could I use a DC Relay?

This is going to be used to physically turn on/off a GPU. Unfortunately my non-Windows OS will not work correctly with the GPU being powered. Currently I remove the power cables by hand, when I need to.

However, I am afraid this will cause problems down the road, as I am often plugging/unplugging those cables.

Comment: have you checked if the GPU power can be disconnected if the data lines are still connected to a live system?

Comment: Yes, that is my current solution. Removing the power while leaving the card plugged in.